# Div triangle not displaying

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a css attempt to display a speech box in my code:

```css
.divContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--color-grey);
  padding: 0 var(--spacing-medium) 0 var(--spacing-medium);
}

.div {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.125em 1.5em;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0.0625rem 0.125rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 -0.0625rem 0.0625rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}

.div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 1.5em;
  border: 0.75rem solid transparent;
  border-top: none;
}
```

JSX

```
<AliceCarousel mouseTracking disableButtonsControls={true}>
    {data.map(person => {
        return (
            <>
                <div className={classes.divContainer}>
                    <Image
                        src={'somesrc.jpg'
                        width={100}
                        height={100}
                    />
                    <div className={classes.div}>
                        {person.text}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    })}
</AliceCarousel>
```

The idea is to have something like this (end goal) :

https://codepen.io/rikschennink/pen/mjywQb

My html code in here is one section of an entire page full of different sections. This particular sections stays right before the page footer.

I can see the box appearing but not the triangle in the speech box.

Any idea why I can't see it?

Sandbox here too for visibility:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-microservice-uv132?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You might post the rendered HTML and CSS in a functional snippet so we can see the outcome. (That's not HTML you're showing, by the way. It's JavaScript/JSX.)

Comment: Try to add border-bottom-color: #fff; to .div::before

Comment: thanks @isherwood have added the codesandbox to my question

Comment: @SabujaKjata - Your suggestions worked when I ran it in the codesandbox-- might make sense to post it as an answer...

Comment: I was asking for a snippet here, in your question, containing HTML and CSS (not another link to elsewhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a transparent border to the left and the right and have a white border on the bottom. Right now you are just adding a transparent border to the whole thing except the top. You can't see something that is transparent so that is why you can't even see the shape it is making. So your triangle should look something like the following:

```
.div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 1.5em;
  border-left: 0.75rem solid transparent;
  border-right: 0.75rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0.75rem solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add border-bottom-color: #fff; to .div::before